# Opcodes PUSH, DUP and SWAP?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, evm, bytecode, opcode

I studied EVM implementations and the bytecode sequences used by them. I wondered that there are three opcodes which are recognized by the EVM but actually are invalid opcodes.

```
B0 PUSH
B1 DUP
B2 SWAP
```

If I execute the opcode `B0` with Geth-EVM i get the following output:

```
./geth-evm-1.8.0-stable --json --code b0 run
{"pc":0,"op":176,"gas":"0x2540be400","gasCost":"0x0","memory":"0x","memSize":0,"stack":[],"depth":1,"opName":"PUSH","error":"invalid opcode 0xb0"}
{"output":"","gasUsed":"0x2540be400","time":137988,"error":"invalid opcode 0xb0"}
{"output":"","gasUsed":"0x2540be400","time":210042,"error":"invalid opcode 0xb0"}
```

As one can see, the opcode `B0` is recognized and processed as `PUSH` opcode. At the same time the error field writes `invalid opcode 0xb0`. The same holds for the other two opcodes. I tested this also with the Parity-EVM implementation. Parity does not know the opcodes and prints directly an error:

```
./parity-evm --json --code b0
{"pc":0,"op":176,"opName":"","gas":"0xffffffffffffffff","gasCost":"0x0","memory":"0x","stack":[],"storage":{},"depth":1}
{"error":"EVM: Bad instruction b0","gasUsed":"ffffffffffffffff","time":9881}
```

Why do these opcodes exist and for what reason? Why does the EVM of go-ethereum know the opcodes but not the implementation of Parity?

EDIT:

I also found this `const` in the go-ethereum source code:

```
// unofficial opcodes used for parsing
const (
    PUSH OpCode = 0xb0 + iota
    DUP
    SWAP
)
```

They mention, that they use it for parsing and they are unofficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SPEC

I don't know what they are for, but they are something implementation specific. Indeed, according to the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) specification ([the yellow paper, Appendix H](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)), there are no opcodes for `0xB0, 0xB1, 0xB2`.
Moreover, there are no `PUSH,DUP` and `SWAP` opcodes, but rather:

1. `0x60 PUSH1, 0x61 PUSH2,..., 0x7f PUSH32`
2. `0x80 DUP1, 0x81 DUP2, ..., 0x8f DUP16`
3. `0x90 SWAP1, 0x91 SWAP2, ..., 0x9f SWAP16`

### GETH EVM

By inspecting the geth code one can see, that they define three additional opcodes `PUSH, DUP and SWAP` in the file `core/vm/opcodes.go`. 
The file `core/vm/instructions.go` implements the different opcodes, and it is easy to see that there is no function like (`opPUSH1`, `opDUP1` and `opSWAP1`) but rather there are only three functions with these headers:

1. `makePush(size int64)`
2. `makeDup(size int64)`
3. `makeSwap(size int64)`

Yes they are used for parsing, because they reduce the different PUSH1, etc. cases to only one case, at is easy to see in file `core/vm/jump_table`
[image: e]

Comment: I know all opcodes from the yellow paper and how they work. Therefore, I was wondering about these three. That would be my question: Why are these implemented in the one Geth-EVM and not in Parity-EVM?

Comment: I am currently inspecting the source code. I am not sure, but I do think, that they reduce the different PUSH1,...,PUSH32, function to a single PUSH instruction, so that they can call a single function PUSH(Amount of bytes)..

Comment: I found something in the source code. See my edit pls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think you are right. I was just confused that the Geth-EVM accepted the opcode with a name.